# missing ; before statement

Tags: php, jquery

I am following the exact code from the `PRO PHP AND JQUERY` book. Added this to `firebug`.

```
$("<p>"),{
    "text":"I'm a new paragraph!", 
    "css":{"background":"yellow"}
})
    .prependTo("body");
```

And get and `missing ; before statement` error.. Seems there is an error in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closing parenthesis is inappropriately added after defining the `<p>`. It should be:

```
$("<p>",{
    "text":"I'm a new paragraph!", 
    "css":{"background":"yellow"}
})
    .prependTo("body");
```

Probably just a misprint.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<p>"),{
```

should be

```
$("<p>",{
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary ")" after "

".
Try this:

```
$("<p/>",{
    "text":"I'm a new paragraph!", 
    "css":{"background":"yellow"}
}).prependTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$('<p>', {
    text: 'I\'m a new paragraph!', 
    css: { background: 'yellow' }
}).prependTo( document.body );
```